# Ruby: Using each in erb

Tags: ruby, loops, erb

how i can use the index to reference different variables? variable1, variable2 should be replaced with the content from a ruby file.

```
erb :main, :locals => { :variable0 => "Hallo",  
                        :variabl1 => "World"
                        }                                    
end
```

This code just returns the variablename and not the variable content.

*.erb file:

```
<% (0..1).each do | index | %>.
     <td> <%= "variable"+i.to_s %> </td>
<% end %>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you start appending your variable names with a number like `item1`, `item2`, etc, that is a clear signal that you are doing it wrong and should be using an Array.

Compare the above with this version that uses an array:

```
data = ['Hello', 'World']
erb :main, locals: { data: data }

data.each do |item|
  puts item
end
```